# How to say that something is "current" but at another point in time

Tags: adjectives, tenses

Imagine I want to say

> Each shipment will be automatically created 2 weeks before the day of collection, and priced according to the rates at that moment.

and I want to express "rates at that moment" as "[adjective] rates".

The following attempt produces confusion:

> Each shipment will be automatically created 2 weeks before the day of collection, and priced according to *current* rates.

because it might mean "according to whatever the rates are this very moment"

What's the word that I should use in place of current to express the fact that I want it to be "current at that time"?

Comment: According to the ***then current*** rates

Comment: …according to prevailing rates.

Comment: Alexander, what difficulties d'you see here, please?

"Each shipment will be automatically created…" is a problem but that's not what you're asking about, is it?

Anything before the day - rather than the date -  of collection  is a problem but that's not what you're asking about, is it?

"… priced according to the rates at that moment" is a problem only to people who've researched neither the language nor the rates…

For averything you ask about there are clear conventions and any deviation from them is very, very dangerous.

Comment: I would argue that "the current rates" gets its point across just fine, given the assumption that most readers will tend not to think the narration prescient. When I was reading that, I didn't see a tense problem as I subconsciously assumed "current" meant 'current' within the time-frame of the topic.

Comment: must be of the *quantum entanglement*  magic!

Answer (score -1):

"According to the rates then."

Answer (score -2):

According to the prevailing rates

Comment: I would also suggest reordering things so that the timing isn't lost. "Each shipment will be priced according to prevailing rates and created two weeks before the day of collection."

Comment: If you're going to piggyback on someone else's response, you need to add a supporting reference to make the response worthy of an 'answer'.

Comment: The same ambiguity exists-  prevailing rates now or then?